# Updating database records from a form using Laravel - Request not pulling variable

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to update a grantor's details via a form, however the record in the database table is not registering any changes. The issue appears to concern the Request not picking up the data stored in the variable, as when the code `$grantor->grantor_name= $request->input('grantor_name');` is replaced with `$grantor->grantor_name= "updated_data";`, the database table does update with the "updated_data" string. I will include snippets of my existing code for clarity. Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated!

**Grantor Controller File**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $grantor = Grantor::find($id);
        $grantor->grantor_name= $request->input('grantor_name');
        $grantor->save();
```

**Grantors.edit.blade File**

```
<div class="flex-1 px-10">
      <form method="post" action="{{route('grantors.update', $grantor->id )}}" class="is-readonly"> 
     @csrf
      
        <div class="row">
            @if ($errors->any()) <span>{{ $errors }}</span> @endif
         </div>
         <div class="h-auto md:h-96">

            <!-- item -->
            <div x-data=" {isOpen : false} " class="pt-2 pb-4 border-b border-divider">
              <div @click="isOpen = !isOpen"
                class="flex items-center cursor-pointer text-neutral-darker hover:text-primary-hover"
                :class="{'font-bold' : isOpen}">
                <span class="text-xl md:xl">Grantor Details</span>
                <img class="mb-1 duration-300 ml-4 inset-0 h-6 w-6" :class="{'transform rotate-180' : isOpen}"
                    src="../../img/icon-arrow-down.png" alt="Dropdown-arrow">
              </div>
              <div x-show.transition.duration.300ms.origin.bottom="isOpen" x-cloak @click.away="isOpen = false"
                class="pt-3 text-sm text-neutral">
                 @if($is_editable)
                <div class="flex justify-end">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-edit js-edit"><img class="mb-1 duration-300 ml-4 inset-0 h-6 w-6" src="../../img/edit-icon.svg" alt="edit icon"></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-save js-save"><img class="mb-1 duration-300 ml-4 inset-0 h-6 w-6" src="../../img/save-icon.svg" alt="save icon"></button>
                </div>
                @endif 
                <form class="w-full">
                  <div class="px-6 sm:px-6">
                   <div class="md:flex items-center">
                    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 flex flex-col">
                      <div class="md:flex md:items-center">
                        <label for="grantor_name" class="font-bold text-neutral-darker leading-none pr-4" for="inline-full-name" disabled>Grantor/ Company/ Organisation Name *</label>
                        <input class="leading-none text-gray-900 py-2 px-4 w-80 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-700 mt-4 bg-gray-100 border rounded border-gray-200 is-disabled @error('grantor_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="grantor_name" value="{{ $grantor->grantor_name }}" id="grantor_name" type="text" disabled >
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

**Tenant Routes File**

```
Route::get('/grantors/{id}/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\GrantorController::class, 'edit'])->name('grantors.edit');
Route::post('/grantors/{id}/update', [App\Http\Controllers\GrantorController::class, 'update'])->name('grantors.update');
```

**Grantor Model**

```
protected $table = 'grantors';
protected $fillable= [
    'grantor_name'
]);
```

Comment: dd($request->input()); in controller to see whether you receive granter_name or not

Comment: Thank you, when I try that with `$grantor->grantor_name= $request->input('grantor_name');` I receive the error 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'grantor_name' cannot be null (SQL: update `grantors` set `grantor_name` = ?, `grantors`.`updated_at` = 2022-01-12 10:18:54 where `id` = 2)' so I believe the issue is that the value for grantor_name is not being recognised

Comment: can you send screenshot of dd($request->input()) result

Comment: Unfortunately I am only new to Stack Overflow so I cannot access the chat yet, but the error I mentioned above is what is returned when the code `$grantor->grantor_name= $request->input('grantor_name');` is used. When I replace it with `$grantor->grantor_name= "updated_data";` the `dd($request->input())` returns `[]` and the database record is changed to 'updated_data'

Answer (score 1):

Your `grantor_name` `input` has the `disabled` attribute applied so will not be passed through as part of the form submission. Remove `disabled` then the `input` plus its `value` be submitted.

If you do not want people amending the value, replace `disabled` with `readonly`.

Additionally, ensure that `value="{{ $grantor->grantor_name }}"` has a value.

**Edit**

I've just noticed you also have an additional nested `form` tag just before your `grantor_name` input. Don't nest `form` elements, so remove that.

Remove any `form` tags that are nested inside of your outer `form` tag. So basically any inside of

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('grantors.update', $grantor->id )}}" class="is-readonly">
```

The one I can see in your example is

```
<form class="w-full">
```

Which is just under your `@endif` and before your `grantor_name` `input`.

Then again do some debugging on `$request->input()` to check if there is a `key/value` pair for `grantor_name`.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the `disabled` attribute but the error 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'grantor_name' cannot be null (SQL: update grantors set grantor_name = ?, grantors.updated_at = 2022-01-12 10:18:54 where id = 2)' is still being returned - I feel like the issue is that the value in $grantor->grantor_name is not being pulled through, however on the edit page the fields are all prepopulated with the current fields from the database table so I do not know why it is not picking up this value

Comment: @ConlaodhQuinn I have made an edit to my answer as I noticed there was an additional `form` tag I hadn't previously noticed in your code.

Comment: Thanks for you help so far, would you mind highlighting in my code what `form` tag exactly should be removed?

Comment: Thanks again for your edits, I have removed the extra form tag but still getting the same error - is there a reason perhaps related to the `$request` not being able to access the data from `$grantor->grantor_name`? As I know that the form is working and updating the database with a string, just not with the `$grantor->grantor_name` value

Comment: @ConlaodhQuinn You need to check the value of `grantor_name` in your `$request` object. Do a `dd($request->input());` at the start of your `update` function and check that there is an element for `grantor_name` and that it has the expected value. If you don't see `grantor_value` in output, then it is not being submitted by your form for some reason.

Comment: When I `dd($request->input());` at the beginning of the update function, there is nothing returned only `[]` - have you any idea why it would not be submitted by the form?

Comment: @ConlaodhQuinn There must be something in your `blade` file preventing anything being submitted. Try stripping your form back to it's very basics (start with just an `input` and `button` to confirm anything can get through) then start adding your form back in until you don't get any data being submitted and then you have found the culprit. Additionally, might be an idea to update your question with all the HTML from your `blade` file.